# Invalid access to memory location

Tags: c#, winforms

My code is looks like this:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Width = 700;
browser.Height = 200;
**browser.Url = new Uri("about:blank");**
browser.DocumentText = mytext;
```

and the error occurred in highlighted line ie:

> BadImageFormatException was unhandled: Invalid access to memory location. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E6).

I have search in many forums and already change my Project Property Platform to Any CPU. But its not works.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How about adding the browser control to a form before navigating? In addition, try inserting "Application.DoEvents()" before/after navigating.

Comment: It sounds it's more related your your SW configuration than to your code. What's OS and IE version?

Comment: @UweKeim when I add the control same error occured. `Invalid access to memory location`

Comment: @Adriano Yes I also thinks that its a configuration problem because It is working fine before deployment and after many days when I run that application again I get this error... My OS is Win 7 its an Windows Application..

Comment: It does not make sense that you can modify the `Width` and `Height` of this property but not a `Url` proeprty. It only makes sense if the `WebBrowser` is not actually been added to the Form yet, because when you attempt to set a property that could be `null` to a control that doesn't exist yet, that could cause a memory exception like this.  This isn't a system configuration problem `WebBrowser` works the same no matter what version of Windows (x86 or x64 ).  Just to confirm a thought what version of IE is installed?

Comment: But it is working fine in the past. After deployment and configuration changes in Property of applications it is not working..

Comment: Did you try "Application.DoEvents()" call? Helped me once with a similar issue.

Comment: Have you fixed it up ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
HtmlDocument objHtmlDoc = webBrowser1.Document;
objHtmlDoc.Write("<span style=\"font-size:10px\">TEXT </span>");
panel1.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: Its not worked because I am also adding webbrowser control in Panel on runtime `PnlWebBrowser.Controls.Add(browser);`.

Answer (score -1):

BadImageFormatException is often related to bitness - try changing the architecture (x86, x64) of your product's build to match that of the DLLs you are referencing.

Comment: Yes and no. It's something in the unmanaged world but the web control can be used even if compiled with AnyCPU.

Comment: @canhazbits - `WebBrowser` is contained within `System.Windows.Forms.dll` your comment makes no sense.

Comment: @canhazbits Yes it's `Platform` is set to Any CPU.